# How do I exclude weekends from my monthly day counter?

Tags: r, date

I currently have the following code below which I would like to tweak, specifically the day counter so that it excludes the weekend. The script is tied to a visualization in a dashboard that get updated daily with the last row being today's only data entry. In other words, one row is added everyday with Sales data.

So, from day 1 to 15, the day counter should include the following values: (0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10)

Lastly, how do I update the DailyAverage measure so that it automatically displays 0 if the denominator is equal to 0? Sunday was the first day of this month, so the visualization might have crashed then.

```
library(timeDate)

FirstDayInMonth<-timeFirstDayInMonth(Sys.Date())

LineChart$CumMQL<-cumsum(LineChart$`Sales`)
LineChart$DayCounter<-as.integer(as.Date(LineChart$`Reporting Date`)-as.Date(FirstDayInMonth))+1
LineChart$DailyAverage<-LineChart$CumSales/LineChart$DayCounter

final<-LineChart[as.Date(LineChart$`Reporting Date`)<Sys.Date(),]

final
```

```
Reporting Date                   Sales CumSales DayCounter  DailyAverage 
1      2022-05-01                   0      0          1  0.0000000000000    
2      2022-05-02                  16     16          2  8.0000000000000    
3      2022-05-03                  11     27          3  9.0000000000000    
4      2022-05-04                  25     52          4 13.0000000000000    
5      2022-05-05                  22     74          5 14.8000000000000    
6      2022-05-06                  21     95          6 15.8333333333333    
7      2022-05-07                   0     95          7 13.5714285714286    
8      2022-05-08                   0     95          8 11.8750000000000    
9      2022-05-09                  37    132          9 14.6666666666667    
10     2022-05-10                  21    153         10 15.3000000000000    
11     2022-05-11                  14    167         11 15.1818181818182    
12     2022-05-12                  20    187         12 15.5833333333333    
13     2022-05-13                  18    205         13 15.7692307692308    
14     2022-05-14                   0    205         14 14.6428571428571    
15     2022-05-15                   0    205         15 13.6666666666667
```

Comment: I recommend checking out the lubridate package. You can use the wday function to add a column that labels the day of the week and then you can filter the dataframe. Your second question can be answered with an if statement I believe

Comment: While zero sales days are obvious, they can be used but there are other reasons than weekdays for zero sales sometimes. Since you are using the timeDate package, I suggest you create a col using the dayOfWeek() function and filter. Lubridate also has a function wday() if you ever go that route. You could use the day of the year functions in either package to exclude business holidays the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example showing one way of identifying weekdays. You could then `filter(weekday == TRUE)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(clock)
library(almanac)

# Create rule
wday <- daily() |> recur_on_weekdays() 

# Sample dates
tibble(date = date_seq(as.Date("2022-05-01"), by = duration_days(1), total_size = 15)) |> 
  # Check against rule
  mutate(weekday = alma_in(date, wday))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 2
#>    date       weekday
#>    <date>     <lgl>  
#>  1 2022-05-01 FALSE  
#>  2 2022-05-02 TRUE   
#>  3 2022-05-03 TRUE   
#>  4 2022-05-04 TRUE   
#>  5 2022-05-05 TRUE   
#>  6 2022-05-06 TRUE   
#>  7 2022-05-07 FALSE  
#>  8 2022-05-08 FALSE  
#>  9 2022-05-09 TRUE   
#> 10 2022-05-10 TRUE   
#> 11 2022-05-11 TRUE   
#> 12 2022-05-12 TRUE   
#> 13 2022-05-13 TRUE   
#> 14 2022-05-14 FALSE  
#> 15 2022-05-15 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>